# facebook messenger hide messages

Tags: facebook, messenger

I created a bot for Messenger using Microsoft Bot framework.
this bot is connected to a Facebook Page. I noticed that every single messages related to a conversation with the bot, they are visible in the Facebook page admin panel under "messages".

is it possible to disable the logging of these messages ?

thank you 
Antony

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem, did you solve it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure marking a message as seen by the bot may solve this. I have also been trying to solve this but even sending the `mark_seen` wont actually mark the messages as seen. Starting to think its an issue with the action since `typing_on` and `typing_off` actions work fine.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/sender-actions